# How to make a select option without using HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm kind of new to programing. I know the basics of html, css, javascript and php. I want to make a select option without using HTML, because for what I know you can not style the inside of the select so much.

So I was hoping that you can use javascript to make something similar. I want to pick a date like this website does when their're going to reserve a table: https://www.bookatable.co.uk/stockholm-restaurants

For what I can see in their code they are using list, so they have to use some kind of code to accomplish a select-option-style.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: doing this without html is like using butter without a bread

Comment: I don't really understand your question. just tell me what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Hi Tobias, are you using any javascript library ? if yes which is it ? if you want suggestions go for angular

Comment: I'd just like to say that - *personally* speaking - I actually despise "custom" JS-powered form controls. Mostly because they almost never replicate the original properly. For instance, "fancy" radio buttons don't respond to arrow keys. Many don't handle `Tab`. And for Select boxes, almost none of them actually work on mobile devices. See also: [Non-Native UI Sucks](https://blog.codinghorror.com/non-native-ui-sucks/)

Comment: The link you just put here is using `select` tag of HTML and the plugin that they use; it uses the options to render it feel like a list box. kind of a wrapper. If you closely look while inspecting elements in console inspector then you'll be able to see select tab after list element. I think you probably need something similar to https://select2.org/

Comment: you can google to find lots of JavaScript code libraries which will do this kind of thing. Very little point in making your own version unless you want to do an academic exercise to learn the techniques. Niet's point above is valid though, some of the examples out there are not very good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Bootstrap Select Plugin](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/). This plugin requires Bootstrap and jQuery. To initialize this plugin, get a `select` element with jQuery (`$(selector)`) and use the `.selectpicker()` method.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.0-beta/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <select class="selectpicker">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
  <option>Option 5</option>
  <option>Option 6</option>
  <option>Option 7</option>
  <option>Option 8</option>
  </select>
  <script>
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  </script>
```

Comment: It kind of worked but the two links to css also styles other things around in  my project, and if I delete the links nothing works. I think I will use the default select, the pluggin is too complicated to edit, thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list containing links to trigger Javascript to set the option.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('hidden-select');
var custom_options = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-option');

for (i = 0; i < custom_options.length; i++) {
  custom_options[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var value = this.getAttribute('data-value');
      select.value = value;
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden-select {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="hidden-select" id="hidden-select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<ul class="custom-select">
  <li><a class="custom-option" href="#" data-value="1">1</a></li>
  <li><a class="custom-option" href="#" data-value="2">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

If i may understand you clearly, you want a very sweet and cool design to your element because select option may not give you what you want. 
you can make use of **javascript** and any other for **element** you are familiar with to design it as you want.

```
<i onclick="optionSelect('1');">Your preferred element here 1</i>
<i onclick="optionSelect('2');">Your preferred element here 2</i>
<i onclick="optionSelect('3');">Your preferred element here 3</i>
<i onclick="optionSelect('4');">Your preferred element here 4</i>

<javascript>

var selectedOption = '0';

function optionSelect(sel){
selectedOption = sel;
}

</javascript>
```

You can also get to change the color of the element that fired the function....

The above code works perfect when submitting your form via ajax or any js framework.

But if you want it in a form, then you can hide your form option element and change it value as they click

Comment: using the `onclick` attribute is something of the past century and is not recommended. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score -2):

You could create a new component yourself.
In this case you will gain control to all behavior of they.
And must have to control all elements, events and layout.

```
<div id="my-element">
  <input class="visible_field" type="text"/>
  <ul class="list_of_options" hidden>
    <li class="option" option-value="value">Option1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp